# Unable to cast EventArgs object to PaintEventArgs when drawing a line in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, paint

I've recently been learning how to paint lines (and other shapes) onto forms in vb.net. However, I keep running into the same problem that no guides or queries seem to acknowledge. Painting seems to require using subs with the PaintEventArgs class, whereas regular subs use EventArgs (or something else). Because of this, calling the subs I need for drawing lines always results in the same error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs'.'

As I said, none of the guides or questions I've seen anywhere (including this site) seem to mention this. They show the different subs but they never say how they run together.

The code I've been using to learn and test this is:

```
Public Class Form1
    Sub TestDraw(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim TestPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 5.0)
        Dim StartPoint As New Point(50, 50)
        Dim EndPoint As New Point(50, 100)

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(TestPen, StartPoint, EndPoint)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
         TestDraw(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I know there's something wrong here but I just don't know what. I feel kinda stupid but if someone could explain this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Handle the Form1_Paint event.

Comment: #1. The [Paint Event Args](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?view=netframework-4.8) are **Supplied** by the Paint Event Handler.

Comment: #2. Take a read of this article: [How to: Create Graphics Objects for Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-graphics-objects-for-drawing) for a quick example on how to draw shapes

Comment: There is no point in trying to draw anything in the Load event, the window is not yet visible so you couldn't see what you draw.  Just one more way that .NET keeps you out of trouble.  Winforms tells you when you need to draw by generating an event, it passes the data you need to paint correctly.  Select the form, click the lightning bolt icon and double-click "Paint" to add the event handler you need.

Comment: In my opinion, you don't need TestDraw, but move the content to form_load, and you make some change to e.Graphics.DrawLine(TestPen, StartPoint, EndPoint) and add additional code, you create bmp as same size as your form, create graphics from the bmp, for ex: Dim myG As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp), and with this graphic you draw anything, the last set the bmp to BackgroundImage of form. And this will persist...I hope

Comment: I think, you can use the event of Form1_Paint, it will help you, although it will be called each time your form will be painted, for example when mouse pointer change when enter to textbox, when your form is overlapped by anything window etc

Comment: And you can't submit over e as EventArgs from form_load event arguments to TestDraw as PaintEventArgs (this is the cause of InvalidCastException), EventArgs is different from PaintEventArgs. You can make PaintEventArgs like this (just sample): Dim myArgs As New PaintEventArgs(myG, New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), New Size(100, 100)))

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the lovely people in the comments have answered my question, but I can't mark a comment as an answer so I'll post what I've learned here.

I wasn't sure what was meant by handling (still learning, mind), but I took Hans Passant's suggestion, and after seeing the code added in I finally got the idea, and sure enough the line now gets drawn. I also did away with putting the code in a sub, for simplicity, and now the code is:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
        Dim TestPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 5.0)
        Dim StartPoint As New Point(50, 50)
        Dim EndPoint As New Point(50, 100)

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(TestPen, StartPoint, EndPoint)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This works fine; I didn't even need the Form1_Load event handler. However, this only creates the line when the form is loaded; I wanted it to be drawn when a button is clicked. After some digging I found how to do this, so I'll put it in here for extra information should anyone need it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim draw As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
        If draw = True Then
            Dim TestPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 5.0)
            Dim StartPoint As New Point(50, 50)
            Dim EndPoint As New Point(50, 100)

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(TestPen, StartPoint, EndPoint)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        draw = True
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I found that using a Boolean I could set whether or not the lines get drawn when the Paint event is called, so when it starts as False they won't be drawn when the form loads, or any time it's redrawn. Then, when I want them to be drawn, I can click the button, which sets the Boolean to True and invalidates the surface of the form, thus redrawing everything and painting what I need. Maybe this isn't the best way, but it works for me.